Power Automate - Can't Get Tables
I've tried to use file Id, Name, Location, but there's an error every time.

Parameters are:
{
"source": "me",
"drive": "b!rtWTHFS3eEqoKvfx5IlwLahcG6sBdYtApwSkgzcXdaAcsQPEUa2RQIJbq7uebEG8",
"file": "Sheet1"
}
When I choose File Id, the error is BadRequest, and parameters are:
{
"source": "me",
"drive": "b!rtWTHFS3eEqoKvfx5IlwLahcG6sBdYtApwSkgzcXdaAcsQPEUa2RQIJbq7uebEG8",
"file": "{EBF92BF6-14B3-4A83-873C-221C548036B4}"
}

The following steps worked for me. In the example, OneDrive folder Test-Excel only has excel files with table named Table1



Expressions
[File]
concat('/Test-Excel/', items('Apply_to_each_2')?['DisplayName'])

[Rows in the Table]
length(outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value'])


That worked! Thanks
